Deserialize transaction input data with publickey
How can I deserialize input args with publicKey inputs?
Full Code:
const borsh = require('borsh');
const bs58 = require('bs58');

const schema = { 'struct': { 'discriminator': 'u64', 
  'mint': "publicKey", 
  'solAmount': 'u64', 
  'tokenAmount': 'u64', 
  'isBuy': 'bool', 
  'user': "publicKey", 
  'timestamp': 'i64', 
  'virtualSolReserves': 'u64', 
  'virtualTokenReserves': 'u64', 
} };
const encodeddata = "2K7nL28PxCW8ejnyCeuMpbXf8Xj7ysXeidJ55TJtZ8PzmG6NLHutyvhym8DqCYcg92aNSXYc4zw6BTJH2matHQR2vqYABBozk3wQJnArhbuCarwm6a1rdvkWiQS8JzqX5citcf3Hf8VMppEpJHtxDQ7J6FJHdnvUG7tyfqG6iU2wpqKR9MZS8515ZAXq";

const decoded = borsh.deserialize(schema, Buffer.from(bs58.decode(encodeddata)));
console.log(decoded);

I got this error:

throw new ErrorSchema(schema, VALID_OBJECT_KEYS.join(', ') + ' or ' +
VALID_STRING_TYPES.join(', '));
^
Error: Invalid schema: "publicKey" expected option, enum, array, set,
map, struct or u8, u16, u32, u64, u128, i8, i16, i32, i64, i128, f32,
f64, bool, string


I'm not sure about the error but it seems the schema is a not valid JSON. The comma at line 'virtualTokenReserves': 'u64', should be erased (no last comma).

Thanks for your advice.
I checked it, the problem is not like that, unfortunatelly.
I replayced the "publicKey" with 2 u128 (to get the bytes) and it is working well. The problem is that I cant readpubluckey I only can read 2u128 or 4u64. I nether can parse a u256 with the library...

The error says it pretty clearly:

Error: Invalid schema: "publicKey" expected option, enum, array, set, map, struct or u8, u16, u32, u64, u128, i8, i16, i32, i64, i128, f32, f64, bool, string

If you want to do it simply, you can just interpret the public key as 32 bytes, ie:
const schema = { 'struct': { 'discriminator': 'u64', 
  'mint': { array: { type: 'u8', len: 32 }}, 
  'solAmount': 'u64', 
  'tokenAmount': 'u64', 
  'isBuy': 'bool', 
  'user': { array: { type: 'u8', len: 32 }}, 
  'timestamp': 'i64', 
  'virtualSolReserves': 'u64', 
  'virtualTokenReserves': 'u64', 
} };

Note that if you actually want a PublicKey, you'll need to convert from the raw bytes, likely using new PublicKey(...)
